# email thumbnail image

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Is it possible to **add an email thumbnail image** depending on the SFMC send classification that **you've selected**?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the icon an email client like Outlook uses. It has little to do with Marketing Cloud, but is a feature of that email client. I guess you could manipulate it for the 10% (or so) of people who use Outlook through the Sender Profile. Outlook seems to parse out initials from the Display Name used in the Sender Profile. Here's an example of a Marketing Cloud email where "Domain Announcements" (Display Name) -> "DA".

[image]